# How can I create a nonnegative integer regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I want to compile a `Pattern` that matches nonnegative integers. It should look for a sequence of one or more consecutive digits that is not preceded by another digit or a negative sign. I have been able to compile the following:

```
Pattern digit = Pattern.compile("\\d");  //looks for single digits
```

But suppose I declare the following:

```
String a = "90 210";
String b = "-90 210";
String c = "z90p210";
String d = "pz-90210";
```

`digit` would match `"9"`, `"0"`, `"2"`, `"1"`, and `"0"` in all four of these. I'm interested in a `Pattern` that would match `"90"` and `"210"` in `a`, `"210"` in `b`, `"90"` and `"210"` in `c`, and would not match anything in `d`.

Is there a way to disregard sequences of digits preceded by a negative sign or another digit?

Comment: How do you differentiate a sequence of digits preceded by another digit from just a longer sequence?

Comment: Why do you want to write a parser for something that already exist?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for... but the patter "[-\\d\\s]+" will match both a and b

Comment: I want the user to be able to enter a bunch of numbers on a single line, and I want to catch any that are nonnegative integers. The way I differentiate is by whether or not the sequence is both preceded and followed by another digit. I can use the Scanner class's findInLine method, which requires a Pattern defined by a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind assertion: `(?<!...)` *(not preceded by)*

```
Pattern digit = Pattern.compile("(?<![\\d-])\\d+");
```

Comment: Would I be able to do "(?<![\\d-])\\d+(?>![\\d])" so that it doesn't capture just part of a multi-digit number?

Comment: The syntax of a negative lookahead is `(?!...)` but you don't need it, since the quantifier `+` is by default greedy and will take all possible digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s = { "90 210", "-90 210", "z90p210", "pz-90210" };
    for (String str : s) {
        System.out.println(str
                .matches("(-|[A-Za-z])*?\\d+(\\s|[a-zA-Z])+\\d+"));

    }
}

O/P : true
true
true
false
```